# What happens when an in-flight transaction (holdable result set) is rolled back in Derby after a successful commit?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

If I don't close an open `ResultSet` in Derby and the connection is using `ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` for holdability, what happens if I call:

```
connection.commit();
connection.rollback();
```

Is there any risk to calling `rollback()` once I've explicitly committed the current transaction?  I ask because I find I always have to call `rollback()` before I can close the connection or I get an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to call rollback() when you haven't performed any changes to the database.

In fact, I rollback() read-only transactions all the time.

Comment: That's what I figured, but wanted to make sure.  Thanks!